# How do I assign a LPT port for a usb to parallel adapter on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, printer, ms-dos, parallel-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I simulate a parallel (LPT) Printer with a USB Printer?](https://superuser.com/questions/182655/how-do-i-simulate-a-parallel-lpt-printer-with-a-usb-printer)

I have a legacy DOS application that needs to print to a LPT port and only have USB ports on the host machine. I have installed a usb to parallel adapter to connect the printer. The adapter installed correctly with the USB Printer Support driver, however the adapter does not appear as a LPT port.

How do I assign a LPT port to the usb adapter?

Comment: I would suspect you need to review the software it came with, or visit the manufacturers site. What is the adapter you used?

Comment: i am using the prolific usb to parallel adapter. I have used this adapter before and was able to go to the device properties and assign a lpt port. Now, for some reason I can't, the device only appear as a usb port.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps:

1. Do a "right mouse" click on your printers name
2. Choose "Properties" from the popup menu
3. Click on the "Ports" tab at the top
4. Write down the name of your USB port name
5. Click on the "Enable Printer Pooling" checkbox
6. Scroll through all of your listed ports and click on "LPT1" port.
7. Click on "Apply" and "Ok".

Comment: I have implemented this successfully but it does not work consistently. I have posted as a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151931/enabling-printer-pooling-to-make-usb-port-appear-as-lpt-port