# Print text file from command line without shell "print" command

Tags: windows, command-line, printing

I have a printer, an HP DeskJet 712C, that I cannot print to via the shell "print" command in Windows 7 or Windows XP.  I think this is because this particular printer is a "software" printer, something like a "software" modem.  I am, however, able to print from Word, Notepad, and other programs.  Is there some command line utility that I can use to print text files from?

Comment: Is it hooked up via USB or Parallel?  If USB then see this: [How do I simulate a parallel (LPT) Printer with a USB Printer?](http://superuser.com/questions/182655/how-do-i-simulate-a-parallel-lpt-printer-with-a-usb-printer)

Comment: Parallel, I'm afraid.  I've already tried printing via `print -DLPT1` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the notepad command line switch /p?
e.g.

```
notepad.exe /p "c:\test.txt"
```

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389

```
/A <filename> open file as ansi
/W <filename> open file as unicode
/P <filename> print filename
/PT <filename> <printername> <driverdll> <port> print filename to designated printer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell's [`Out-Printer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content './myfile.txt' | Out-Printer
```

You can even specify the name of a printer to use a non-default one, like so:

```
'Hi!' | Out-Printer 'Send to OneNote 2016'
```

That lets me put the text `Hi!` right into OneNote.

Comment: Hi @Ben N  do you have any alternative command for older systems like windows 7 this command is working perfectly on 10

Comment: @Fathy I only know of printing features in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.x. It might be possible to install PowerShell 5.1, e.g. with [this update package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616), but if that doesn't work you'll need to use a different program like circle's answer suggested.