# Printer not working using USB to parallel printer cable

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer

I have an old EPSON LQ300 printer which seems to working perfectly connected to my desktop PC... It has LPT port no USB.. So i wanted to connect it to my laptop. I bought a USB to parallel printer cable and connected it to my lapto which is running Windows 7

The problem is that when i connect the printer it doenst detect the printer although i have installed the correct printer drivers..

It only says

```
unspecified USB 2.0-Print
```

can some one tell me how can i get the printer work?

Comment: Check [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/cant-get-windows-7-to-identify-my-printer/ebe08759-ec2e-4a3e-9fe2-429d96cbd981) answer.

Comment: Did you install any virtual parallel-port driver for your USB dongle?

Comment: I think the problem may be that the printer drivers expect to talk to `LPTn`: [this trick](https://superuser.com/a/182678/327367) may work for you. If not, one of the other answers may help.